# bind on jquery locks up select boxes with ajax

Tags: jquery, binding

I have a simple form in Rails3 that calls AJAX and replaces a table with results

The coffee.js is

```
    id_handler = ->
       $.ajax
          url: "/surveys_search"
          data:
            id: $(this).val()
            name: $(this).prop("name")

    input_handler = ->
       $.ajax
          url: "/surveys_search"
          data:
            search: $(this).val()
            name: $(this).prop("name") 

    $(document).ready ->
      $(document).on "change", "select", id_handler
      $(document).on "keyup", "input", input_handler


      $("#survey_active").bind "change", ->
        $.ajax
          url: "/surveys_search"
          data:
            survey_active: (if $(this).is(":checked") then 1 else 0)
```

My form is

```
  <div class="well  well-small">
    <h4>Quick search</h4>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
      <dt><strong>Quiz:</strong></dt> <dd>
        <%= text_field_tag :surveys_search, params[:surveys_search], :class=>"text-field" %> 
        <%= select_tag 'survey_select', options_from_collection_for_select(Survey.all, 'id', 'name'),:prompt=>"All"%>
        <strong>Published?</strong> <%= check_box_tag 'survey_active' %>

        </dd>
      <dt><strong>Prize:</strong></dt>   <dd><%= text_field_tag :prizes_search, params[:prizes_search], :class=>"text-field" %> <%= select_tag 'prize_select', options_from_collection_for_select(Prize.all, 'id', 'name'),:prompt=>"All"%></dd>
      <dt><strong>Location:</strong></dt>   <dd><%= text_field_tag :locations_search, params[:prizes_search], :class=>"text-field" %> <%= select_tag 'location_select', options_from_collection_for_select(Location.all, 'id', 'name'),:prompt=>"All"%></dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
```

My issues is that when I change the value of the drop down the select box becomes unchangeable until I then reclick another element and then try to re-change it.

Effectively its locking the select drop down when I change it

In the form above I change the TOP / FIRST select drop down, then after the AJAX call the TOP select down is locked and also the BOTTOM / THIRD select box is also in focus, I get two elements in focus at the same time

Can some one explain how to get round it?

Answer (score 0):

```
id_handler = ->
   $.ajax
      url: "/surveys_search"
      data:
        id: $(this).val()
        name: $(this).prop("name") 
      success: $(this).blur()
```